# HibernateSession and EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

A beginning question:

If Hibernate is an implementation of JPA, why doesn't it implement the EntityManager, but the HibernateSession? The two are functionally equivalent (roughtly), but different in use?
Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Hibernate existed waaay before JPA. Moreover JPA was built partially based on Hibernate API

Comment: so, Hibernate is the basis of JPA, not the implementation?Thanks.

Comment: Hibernate implements JPA API, which was invented later and strongly influenced by it. Once the JPA API was published, Hibernate quickly implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

HibernateSession (SessionManager) has further Hibernate functionality than the EntityManager which is just to the JPA specification.  Hibernate has more functionality than this.

Have a read of...

http://www.coderanch.com/t/218543/ORM/databases/difference-between-session-entitymanager

Comment: It seemed, from the read, HIbernate has an EntityManager as well?